# problem solving, minimal sum of one element of n arraylist where neighbour index are not same

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

I get problem solving question like this :

"You decide to go to a mall to buy shirts and/or pants and/or shoes. In the mall there are N different shops. Each shop contains all these three items but at different prices.

Now you have 2 habbits:

- Buy exactly one item from every shop
- Do not buy the same item from the current shop if you had already bought that item from the shop adjacent to the current shop.
  You realize that finding money is hard, so you want to minimize the total money you spend on shopping. "

example
3 (N shops)
1 50 50 (cost of shirt, pants, and shoes in shop 1)
48 50 50 (cost of shirt, pants, and shoes in shop 2)
1 50 50 (cost of shirt, pants, and shoes in shop 3)

so the minimum cost is 52 where i buy shirt in shop 1, pants/shoes in shop 2, and shirt in shop 3.
i cant buy shirt in shop 2 because i buy shirt in shop 1 before.

My first logical is to make all possible list that no same item in adjacent shop, then i will search the minimum cost...
But i get the time limit problem...
there are any ideas to solve it?

sorry if my english is bad...
And thank you so much if you guys respond and answer....

```
public class Solution {
static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data;
static int min;
static int sum;
static int n;

static void permutation(int x, int y){
    if(x==n-1){
        sum+=data.get(x).get(y-1);
        if(sum<min)
            min = sum;
    }
    else{
        sum+=data.get(x).get(y-1);
        if(y==1){
            permutation(x+1,2);
            permutation(x+1,3);
        }
        else if(y==2){
            permutation(x+1,1);
            permutation(x+1,3);
        }
        else if(y==3){
            permutation(x+1,1);
            permutation(x+1,2);
        }
    }
    sum-=data.get(x).get(y-1);
}

static int GetMinCost(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> data){
    sum = 0;
    min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    permutation(0,1);
    permutation(0,2);
    permutation(0,3);

    return min;
} 

static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {       
    int t = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++){
        n = scanner.nextInt();            
        data = new ArrayList<>();           
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            ArrayList<Integer> cost = new ArrayList<>();
            cost.add(scanner.nextInt());
            cost.add(scanner.nextInt());
            cost.add(scanner.nextInt());
            data.add(cost);
        }           
        System.out.println(GetMinCost(data));           
    }       
}
}
```

Comment: must you go through the N shops in order?

Comment: Here's an idea: pass the current minimum around. Once you exceed it in a given branch, you can immediately move to the next one.

Comment: i think yes, it's must in order. @BallisticBlaze, Thank you for your respond....

Comment: i get your idea but don't know to implement it. to get minimum i must process all  data in same level of branch, at recursive way i don't know to try back process. Thank you so much... @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the problem correctly, here is how I would solve it in a pre-filled stores array. We find the smallest value in each store array and exclude the index if it has already been used before in the previous store by storing and comparing it.

```
private int stores[][]={{1,50,50},{48,50,50},{1,50,50},{4,3,5},{20,1,20}};


public void solve() {
    int cost=0;
    int lastItemPurchased=-1;
    for (int storeIndex = 0; storeIndex < stores.length; storeIndex++) {
        int lowestPriceInStoreIndex=getMinValueIndex(stores[storeIndex],lastItemPurchased);
        cost+=stores[storeIndex][lowestPriceInStoreIndex];
        lastItemPurchased=lowestPriceInStoreIndex;
    }
    System.out.println("Cost: "+cost);
}
public int getMinValueIndex(int[] numbers,int indexToExclude){
    int minValue = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<numbers.length;i++){
        if(i==indexToExclude)
            continue;
        if(numbers[i] < numbers[minValue]||minValue==indexToExclude){
            minValue = i;
        }
    }
    return minValue;
}
```

This outputs 75 since it should go 1+50+1+3+20.

Comment: I think the min should be 58=1+50+1+5+1

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond...
but i think the problem don't simple like that, we must consider the previous shop when shopping in next shop because maybe we choose wrong decision..... so i don't use simple iterative but collect all possible in my fisrt logic.
And with your example the min cost must 58.....
example  
10,8,10~
10,10,10~
9,10,8~
15,10,5~
the minimum cost must be 32...
Thank you and sorry

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I'll try edit my answer to solve that issue if I can find a way

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple recursive permutation function will suffice - you just need to keep track of the last item selected and exclude it from the next store.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static int minCost(int[][] prices, int store, int cost, int lastItem)
{
    if(store==prices.length) 
        return cost;

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int item=0; item<prices[store].length; item++)
    {
        if(item != lastItem)
            min = Math.min(min, minCost(prices, store+1, cost+prices[store][item], item));
    }
    return min;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] prices1 = {{1,50,50},{48,50,50},{1,50,50}};             
    System.out.println(minCost(prices1, 0, 0, -1));

    int[][] prices2 = {{1,50,50},{48,50,50},{1,50,50},{4,3,5},{20,1,20}};               
    System.out.println(minCost(prices2, 0, 0, -1));
}
```

Output:

```
52
58
```

Comment: yeah, its great solution....
thank you so much......
but if use recursive it will get time limit problem,
i need the fastest way O(n) maybe.
actually this question is quiz from my senior....